# How to use for_each with additional parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

I am trying to figure out how is `for_each()` used. First, I transformed this loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); ++i){
    myvector[i].a.b. = true;
}
```

into

```
auto enable [](Myvect &mv) {mv.a.b = true;};
for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), enable);
```

This worked fine.

---

Now I would like to use the `for_each` construct for the following loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); ++i){
    foo(local_var, myvector[i]);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not ? Just put `foo(...)` inside your lambda.

Comment: When you say "this worked fine", did you actually run the code and check the results?

Comment: @KerrekSB, it compiled :D I'll test it in a minute.

Comment: @Vorac: I recommend [this advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/596781) on asking questions...

Comment: @KerrekSB, sorry, I forgot a &, when rewriting the code into the qiestion. This is not the actual code, you know.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your first example and a syntax error in your second example. Don't say it compiled when it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put `foo` inside lambda function :

```
for_each( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
                           [local_var](Myvect& mv) // notice reference
                           { 
                           // Assuming you want to modify mv
                              foo(local_var, mv ); 
                           }
        );
```

Comment: I didn't think of that (excuse: Friday late afternoon). Furthermore, I didn't think of putting the lambda inside the `for_each` construct. Thanks.

Comment: @Vorac, if you don't like lambda inside `for_each`, you can always have a functor.